# Point cloud denoising with PDAL

Tags: python-3.x, point-clouds, pdal

I have very dense single return point cloud collected with ground Lidar and consisting of more than 8 000 000 points in approximately 700 square meters. It consists of noise points which I would like to remove. I am using filters.outlier in PDAL pipeline in Python 3.6.

```
json = """{
  "pipeline":[
    {
      "type":"readers.las",
      "filename":"/LASfiles/9A-1B_subset15m.las"
    },
    {
      "type":"filters.outlier",
      "method":"radius",
      "radius":1.0,
      "min_k":4
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.las",
      "filename":"/LASfiles/9A-1B_sub15m_denoise.las"
    }
  ]
}"""

import pdal
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json)
pipeline.validate() 
pipeline.execute()
```

Code runs well, but creates the same point cloud as original one, I tried to change the values of the radius, but getting the same result. I would greatly appreciate if someone gives me a hint on what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy one. If you take another look at the [documentation](https://pdal.io/stages/filters.outlier.html#filters-outlier), you'll find this little snippet:

> It is worth noting that both filtering methods simply apply a classification value of 7 to the noise points (per the LAS specification). To remove the noise points altogether, users can add a range filter to their pipeline, downstream from the outlier filter.

Try adding the following to your pipeline following the outlier filter.

```
{
    "type":"filters.range",
    "limits":"Classification![7:7]"
}
```

This will pass every point with a classification value not equal to 7 (which would indicate noise), and drop all others.

Comment: thank you for helping @chambbj. The problem is that my las file is from single return terrestrial lidar and not classified. Is there any other way of removing the noise using PDAL in my case?

Comment: @Sher did you try my recommendation yet? It will do just what you are looking for. Even if your data does not have classifications to start with, the outlier filter is using the classifications to mark the noise points, but leaving them in the file. The range filter will remove the noise points.

Comment: yes I did, but the code run 24 hours and didn't finish, then I stopped, because I thought there is something wrong with this code. I will try again and let you know.

Comment: I obviously don't know your data, but maybe you need to rethink the radius you are using in the outlier filter.

Comment: It would also be good to know if you changed anything else from your original run (before adding the range filter), as you didn't mention anything about the lengthy runtime in the original query. The range filter should not significantly impact the runtime; most of the time would be spent making the nearest neighbor queries within the outlier filter itself.

Comment: Thanks @chambbj. Original run about 1-2 minutes only but didn't filter the ground as I said before. I didn't change anything from original except adding a range filter as you suggested. It is the second day since the code is running non-stop. I think there is something wrong.

Comment: data is 300 gb of las file

Comment: Something isn't quite adding up to me. I'm imagining you have run two pipelines, **using the same 300 GB file each time**. The first pipeline, as written in your question took 1-2 minutes, and the second has been running for over 24 hours, simply by adding a range filter? Can you post the full pipeline that is taking so long?

Comment: Here is the pipeline, file size is 300 mb not gb, sorry for typo. 
`json = """{ "pipeline":[ {"type":"readers.las", "filename":"/9A-1B_subset15m.las"}, { "type":"filters.outlier", "method":"radius", "radius":10, "min_k":4 }, { "type":"filters.range", "limits":"Classification![7:7]" }, {"type":"writers.las", "filename":"/9A-1B_sub15m_denoise.las"} ] }""" import pdal pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json) pipeline.validate() pipeline.execute()`. I tried to values for radius, but the same problem occured.